# How to save struct based type with a map property into mongodb

Tags: go, mgo

I want to use mongodb as session storage and save a struct based data type into mongodb.

```
The struct type looks like:

type Session struct {
    Id  string
    Data map[string]interface{}
}
```

And create reference to Session struct type and put some data into properties like:

```
type Authen struct {
    Name, Email string
}
a := &Authen{Name: "Foo", Email: "foo@example.com"}

s := &Session{}
s.Id = "555555"
s.Data["logged"] = a
```

How to save the session data `s` into mongodb and how to query those data back and save into a reference again?
I think the problem can occurs with the data property of type `map[string]interface{}`.

As driver to mongodb I would use [mgo](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing special to be done for inserts. Just insert that session value into the database as usual, and the map type will be properly inserted:

```
err := collection.Insert(&session)
```

Assuming the structure described, this will insert the following document into the database:

```
{id: "555555", data: {logged: {name: "foo", email: "foo@example.com"}}}
```

You cannot easily query it back like that, though, because the `map[string]interface{}` does not give the bson package a good hint about what the value type is (it'll end up as a map, instead of `Authen`). To workaround this, you'd need to implement the [bson.Setter](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interface in the type used by the `Data` field.